# Im having difficulty setting my OleDb connection

Tags: c#, oledb

Hi there I am trying to establish a connection to a data source and extract the information and display it in a grid view. The problem is  that i always get null value for ada. Is it possible to have mistyped the query or is there something wrong with the adapter?

Furthermore I am using the myInt variable to insert different data sources because i hav to process more than one file, maybe this could be problematic as well.

```
try
            {
                //establish connectioin
                OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(("provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0; " + ("data source=" + myInt + ";" + "Extended Properties=Excel 8.0;")));

               OleDbDataAdapter ada = new OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM MarkingSheet$]", conn);

                DataSet ds = new DataSet();

               ada.Fill(ds);
               dataGridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables[0].DefaultView;

               conn.Close();
            }
```

ANSWER 
Thats what worked for me

```
OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + myPath + ";Excel 12.0;HDR=YES;"); ;
              conn.Open();
              OleDbDataAdapter ada = new OleDbDataAdapter("select * from [Marking Sheet$]", conn); ;
               DataSet ds = new DataSet();
               ada.Fill(ds);
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the sql to

```
"SELECT * FROM [MarkingSheet$]"
```

since there's a missing opening bracket.

Comment: What is `null`, what does `myInt` contain? (the name suggest an int what would not work, of course)

Comment: I corrected it its a path to the actual excel file. I get a null value for the adapter @Tim Schmelter

Comment: Does the file contain Header Columns?

Comment: No. The data in the file is quite difficult to explain there a couple of rows with explanations and after that some columns with information that I need (tbh it resembles a word file with a table). Getting the value from certain columns will do too. I dont need to read the whole worksheet. @Tim Schmelter

Answer (score 0):

The Fault in your code is that you havent opened a connection when you attempt to fill the Adapter. Your SQL Statement is also wrong. You may also wan wish to bind the DataTable to the DataGridView too like this :-

```
 try
     {

         OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(("provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0; " + ("data source=" + myInt + ";" + "Extended Properties=Excel 8.0;")));

         OleDbDataAdapter ada = new OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM [MarkingSheet$]", conn);

         DataSet ds = new DataSet();

         conn.Open();             

         ada.Fill(ds.Tables[0]);

         conn.Close();

         BindingSource bs = new BindingSource();
         bs.Datasource = ds.Tables[0];

         dataGridView1.DataSource = bs;

      }
  catch(OledbException x)
      {
        // Handle Exception
      }
```

EDIT ****

Try Changing your connection string to :-

```
string connString = "provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data source=" + myInt + ";Extended Properties=Excel 8.0;HDR=Yes;IMEX=1\";";
```